# Creating column data from lists

Tags: python, text, format, tabular

I have a text file that contains the following data:

```
['p2_18c', 'p2_19c', 'p2_20c', 'p2_21c', 'p2_22c', 'p2_24c', 'p2_27c']
0.5180625  
0.5058125
nan
0.484625
0.484
0.455666666667
0.397214285714
```

What I would like to do with this data is reformat it using python such that it looks like this:

```
2            18            0.5180625
2            19            0.5058125
2            20            nan
2            21            0.484625
2            22            0.484
2            24            0.455666666667
2            27            0.397214285714
```

Is this even possible, if so how would I go about starting it and if it's not possible, what do you think is the closest approximation to this I could get?  As always, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would parse the first line as a Python-list using `ast.literal_eval`, then split each element to get first and second column, and iterate over all remaining lines to get the third column.

This code

```
from ast import literal_eval

file_name = "20115571.txt"
file_name_out = "20115571_out.txt"

with open(file_name) as fh, open(file_name_out,"w") as fh_out:
    first_line = fh.readline()
    values = literal_eval(first_line)
    for value, line in zip(values, fh):
        first_column = value[1]
        second_column = value[3:5]
        third_column = line.strip()
        fh_out.write("%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (first_column, second_column, third_column))
```

will write to the output file the following:

```
2   18  0.5180625
2   19  0.5058125
2   20  nan
2   21  0.484625
2   22  0.484
2   24  0.455666666667
2   27  0.397214285714
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the ways would be like this:

```
>>> import ast
>>> data=open('./text.txt','r').readlines()
>>> a=[x.strip('pc').split('_') for x in ast.literal_eval(data[0].strip())]
>>> for x,y in zip(a,data[1:]):
    x.append(y.strip())


>>> a
[['2', '18', '0.5180625'], ['2', '19', '0.5058125'], ['2', '20', 'nan'], ['2', '21', '0.484625'], ['2', '22', '0.484'], ['2', '24', '0.455666666667'], ['2', '27', '0.397214285714']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$ cat t.py
#/usr/bin/env python

with open("data") as file:
    col_1_2=eval(file.readline().strip())

    for row in col_1_2:
        print "\t".join(row[1:-1].split('_') + [file.readline().strip()])
```

which gives:

```
$ python t.py 
2   18  0.5180625
2   19  0.5058125
2   20  nan
2   21  0.484625
2   22  0.484
2   24  0.455666666667
2   27  0.397214285714
```

Note that if you do not trust the contents of the file, you should user `ast.literal_val`rather than simply `eval`.